# Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I was trying to use ajax for a simple like section in a django website. the like button on being clicked likes the post but the html isn't changed. If i refresh the page the html changes.

the console shows the following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined
>       at Object.success ((index):271)
>       at u (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at k (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:2)

the javascript is given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(event){
    $(document).on('click','#like', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var pk= $(this).attr('value');
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'{% url "like_post" post.id %}',
        data:{'blog_id':pk,'csrfmiddlewaretoken':'{{ csrf_token}}'},
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(event){
          $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
        },
        fail:function(rs, e){
          console.log(rs, responseText);
        },
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

html of the section

```
<div>
            <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.id %}">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% if is_liked %}

                    <button id="like" type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn ">unlike</button>

              {% else %}

                    <button id="like" type='submit' name='blog_id' value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn ">like</button>
              {% endif %}
            </form>
</div>
```

the below is the code of the html page

```
<div id="like-section">

              {% include 'blog/like_section.html' %}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable 'response' isn't defined. Your ajax success handler has 'event', change 'event' to 'response' and it should work.

```
success: function(response){
    $('#like-section').html(response['form'])
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your success method doesn't know what response is. Try passing response instead of event, checking event[response]['form'], or log the event object to find what you need.